# Not able to create Modern UI Pages in Pages Library/Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages, modern-pages

I am trying to create SharePoint Modern UI Pages in library other than Site Pages Library like Document Library and Pages Library but with no success.

Also I don't see any way to create another Site Pages Library.

Is there anyway to create Modern UI Pages in other library without writing any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you have activated "Site Pages" feature at site feature level.

Then go to the library that you want to create modern pages, and go to Library settings->Advanced settings->"Allow management of content types", set Yes.

Then click "Add from existing site content types", select content type from "Document content type" and select "Site Page" to add. Click OK:
[image]

After that, you can create modern page via New->Site Page:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
But the new sitepage is created in SitePages Library not in the document library.

Comment: You can add the content type in the desired document library.

Comment: This doesn't work even with the site page content type added. Another Msft mess.